# Are previous versions of a question/answer indexable by Google?

Tags: discussion, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Q&A Revisions Should be Hidden from Search Engines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14028/qa-revisions-should-be-hidden-from-search-engines)

Are previous versions of a question/answer indexable by Google ?

Meaning, if a question is updated, there is still a trace of the old text under the revision history log. Is this page hidden from robots ?

Comment: Yes, feature-completed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14028/qa-revisions-should-be-hidden-from-search-engines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the robots.txt file and you'll see this chunk:

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /
Disallow: /posts
Disallow: /posts/
```

All of the revision histories of each post sit in the `posts` folder.

Disallow here means that if the search engines are playing nice, [or they take the lines as inherited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14028/qa-revisions-should-be-hidden-from-search-engines), they won't index the revision history.

Comment: I have no idea how I could have missed it, looks like I'm blind. +1